# LINQ: transform an array [,] into array[]

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0

I know this is kind of a dumb question, but does anyone have an elegant (or non-elegant) LINQ approach to transform a 2D array (object[,]) into a 1D array (object[]) comprised of the first dimension of the 2D array?

Example:

```
        // I'd like to have the following array
        object[,] dim2 = {{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}};

        // converted into this kind of an array...  :)
        object[] dim1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Comment: Sample input and output would make it easier to interpret your question correct.

Comment: Ok - added example as you requested!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You claim that you want `a 1D array (object[]) comprised of the first dimension of the 2D array`, so I assume you are trying to select a subset of the original 2D array.

```
int[,] foo = new int[2, 3]
{
  {1,2,3},
  {4,5,6}
};

int[] first = Enumerable.Range(0, foo.GetLength(0))
                        .Select(i => foo[i, 0])
                        .ToArray();

// first == {1, 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Elisha had posted an answer (didn't compile initially) also, which I was investigating this afternoon.  I don't know why he deleted his answer, but I carried on with his code example until everything got worked out, and it also gives me what I need:

```
object[,] dim2 = 
   {{"ADP", "Australia"}, {"CDN", "Canada"}, {"USD", "United States"}};

object[] dim1 = dim2.Cast<object>().ToArray();

// dim1 = {"ADP", "CDN", "USD"}
```

This code compiles and returns the expected results.  I glad about the .Cast(), and that I only needed the **first** dimension, not the second.

Comment: In the example here of [country_code,country_name], I would recommend using a dictionary rather than an array[,], if possible.  You could then just read the keys of the dictionary to get the "first dimension".

Comment: @Robert: Yeah, good point.  The problem is that the 2d array is actually being provided from an Excel VSTO Range.get_Value() call.

Comment: When I run that code, I get `dim1 = {"ADP", "Australia", "CDN", "Canada", "USD", "United States"}`

Comment: @Greg, absolutely right.  Sorry about that.  I was actually working with a 2-dimensional array returned from Excel.  The second dimension turned out to be empty, which was why I was getting the expected results.  So now I can see this is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for a collection of collections (instead of an array of arrays), you can do:

```
mainCollection.Select(subCollection => subCollection.First());
```

Comment: @Mike, thanks for pointing that out.  But the 2 dimensional array is being passed back from an external function, so out of my control.